# PHP - file_get_contents() reading chunks gets slower with time

Tags: javascript, php, file, file-get-contents, indexeddb

I'm making some tests to store large files locally with IndexedDb API, and I'm using PHP with JSON (and AJAX on Javascript's side) to receive the file data.

Actually, I'm trying to get some videos and, to do so, I use the following PHP code:

```
$content_ar['content'] = base64_encode(file_get_contents("../video_src.mp4", false, NULL, $bytes_from, $package_size)));
return json_encode($content_ar);
```

*I know `base64_encode` will deliver 1/3 more of information than the original, but that's not the problem right now as it's the only way I know how to retrieve binary data without losing it on the way.*

As you can see, **I specify from which byte it has to start** to read and how many of them I want to retrieve. So, on my JS side, I know how much of the file I have already stored and **I ask the script to get me from `actual_size` to `actual_size + $package_size` bytes**.

What I'm seeing already is that the scripts seems to run more slowly as time goes by and depending on the file size. I'm trying to understand what happens there.

I've read that file_get_contents() stores the file contents in memory, so with big files it could be a problem (that's why I'm reading it in chunks).

But seeing it gets slower with big files (and time), may it be possible that it's still storing the whole file on memory and then delivering me the chunk I tell it to? Like it loads everything and then returns the part I demand?

Or is it just storing everything until the `$bytes_from + $package_size` (that's why it gets slower with time, as it increases)?

If any of the above, is there any way to get it to run more efficiently and improve performance? Maybe I have to do some operations before or after to empty memory resources?

**EDIT:**

I've made a screenshot showing the difference (in ms) of the moment I make the call to get the file bytes I need, and the right moment when I receive the AJAX response (before I do anything with the received data, so Javascript has no impact on the performance). Here it is:

[image: Time increases as file bytes do so.]

As you can see, it's increasing with every call.

**I think the problem is the time it spends to get to the initial byte I need.** It does not load the whole file into memory, but it's slow until getting into the first byte to read, so as it increases the initial point, it takes more time.

**EDIT 2:**

Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm JSON encoding the base64 content? I've been making some performance tests and I've seen that setting `$content_ar['content'] = strlen(base64_encode(file...))` is done in so much less time (when, theorically, it's doing the same work).

However, if that's the case, **I still cannot understand why it increases the slowness** among time. The work of encoding the same length of bytes **should take the same amount of time**, isn't it?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Was the size of your memory limit in your php.ini file? I would try increasing that limit.

Comment: You can always resort to good old `fopen()` + `fread()`... You can also verify memory usage with `memory_get_usage()`.

Comment: The size on my `php.ini` file is `memory_limit = 512M`.  However, it should not be the solution to increase that limit, because I cannot grant how much the videos will be in size, and I cannot set it to 4GB... If the problem is that `file_get_contents()` stores the whole file in memory, then the solution is to find another way to get the file data.

Comment: I don't understand the main purpose of all of this...

Comment: The main purpose of all this is to get the video file by reading it in PHP and delivering to Javascript code to process it. To do so, I'm using `file_get_contents()` but it seems to be not good with performance as file gets bigger or as time goes by. What I'm asking is, why is it happening if I'm telling it to read it in chunks (so, DO NOT store the whole file in memory), and if it's the reason, I'm trying to find out another way around to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you, @ÁlvaroGonzález for your idea. Does this mean that in fact `file_get_contents()` is still loading the whole file into memory even when I'm telling it to read it from a specified length to another?

Comment: try it out. `$before = memory_get_peak_usage(); ... do file_stuff; $after = memory_get_peak_usage();` and see if there's a spike. if f_g_c is indeed stupidly loading the entire file before extracting the chunk you've specified, then DON'T use it. fopen/fread/fclose yourself.

Comment: I've never done it myself. All the manual seems to say is that that performance depends entirely on OS and type of resouce.

Comment: Are the videos on your server or somewhere distant ?

Comment: The videos are on the same server. If they were on external, I could understand that it may be because of the external server bandwidth... however, on the same server, it's kind strange :S That's why I'm thinking it's because `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: I think you should try the good old method fopen & fread...

Comment: I'm testing right now the `memory_get_peak_usage()` method suggested by @MarcB but as some of you suggested, I will also give it a try on `fopen()` and `fread()`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález For an ordinary file on the local server I would be surprised if it reads the whole thing into memory. That would be necessary for a type of resource that doesn't allow seeking, like a web URL or a named pipe.

Comment: I think I get it, and your solution is `readfile()`, don't forget to use `ob_end_clean` is any buffer is on before using this function.

Comment: Also file_get_contents return the file as a string, and not as a binary file, which is what you want for a video file.

Comment: It seems not to be the problem. With every test I've made, I get the same results for `memory_get_peak_usage()`, which is `786432 bytes` of difference between before and after `file_get_contents()`, and that is near the `512 Kb + base64` extra data. It seems that is not allocating the whole file into memory... So now I cannot understand why it takes longer as the file gets bigger or as time passes by. I guess I will use `fread()` or `readfile()` as you suggested.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not that it's allocating the whole file into memory, but that it has to go until the point. I mean, it just allocates the bytes I tell it I want, but it has to read the whole file until it gets on `$bytes_from` and this is what is taking the whole time. It's not a problem of memory allocation, but of performance when pointing to the file's start byte I need. I will try now with `fread()` and `readfile()`

Comment: I'm doing some performance tests, and it seems that it's not `file_get_contents()` the problem. I'm using `json_encode()` to return the content (because it's part of an array) so, I'm JSON encoding a `base64` string. Could it have something to do with it?

Comment: Since `json_encode()` loads everything into memory, yes, it's the most obvious bottleneck.

Comment: Yes, but the simple `json_encode()` thing cannot be the only problem, since every time I make the call I retrieve the same amount of bytes (786432 as I wrote before). Being the bottleneck is logical, but not increasing over time since every call should take the same as it is encoding the same length.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed your edited code. Yes, I guess memory usage should be constant, JSON or not, assuming you dump chunks immediately rather than storing them in a variable. At this point, I suspect only some careful testing (one thing at a time) can shred light on the issue.